# Pythonic way to generate array with one fixed and one random column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My task is to

> Form array X of dimension 1000x2 by setting first column equal to 1 and drawing 1000
> independent random numbers to second column from standard normal distribution.

My solution would be

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.ones(1000)
X2 = np.random.randn(1000)
X = np.vstack([X1,X2]).transpose()
```

Now I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way to achieve the task. Maybe even a one liner?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't simply

```
np.stack([np.ones(1000), np.random.randn(1000)])
```

do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:

```
X = np.vstack([np.ones(1000),np.random.randn(1000)]).transpose()
```

One-liners are not necessarily better

Comment: So, you suggest using my solution, i.e. three lines?

Comment: If it makes it more readable, sure

Comment: You could use better variable names, e.g. replace `X1` with `constant` and `X2` with `random_normal`

Comment: Why do you use transpose()?

Comment: @pao I just copied his code, which ended with a transpose

Comment: ok thank you, I just wanted to know why transpose is used. @XDAF

Comment: @pao Transpose is used to get an array with ones in the first column and random numbers in the second column. Otherwise, the array has a shape of 2 x 1000, i.e., ones are in the first row and the random numbers in the second.

Comment: okay, thank you!